# Passing a function with parameters to react context (react native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

In my code, I have this method called addToArray declared in my App.js file and passed to react context via state like so: 
**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // init values
      array: [],
      ...
      removeFromArray: () => this.removeFromArray(),

      ...
    }
  }
  fetchArray = async () => {
      ...
      this.setState({ array: result });


    } catch (e) {
      alert('Error occured and nothing could be fetched');
    }
  }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchArray();
    ...
  }
    ...

  removeFromArray = (id) => {
    ...
    alert(id);
  }
  render() {
    // variables to init contexts with
    const {
      array,
      removeFromArray
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={{
        array,
        removeFromArray
      }} >
          <Routes />
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The context is declared like this: 
**Context.js**

```
export const GlobalContext = React.createContext({
 array: [],
 removeFromArray: () => { } 
});
```

and is called like this:

```
 const btn = (props) => {
      const GlobalCtx = useContext(GlobalContext);
      return(
        <View style={card.editOpacity}>
         <Icon
           name="minus-circle"
           type='font-awesome'
           color='red'
           onPress={() => {
             GlobalCtx.removeFromArray(props.id)
            }} />
          <Text style={card.header}>{props.title}</Text>
         </View>
      );
```

for some reason it is not working, but I think it may have to do with the parameters and the way it's being passed to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to put the `removeFromArray` function inside `state`. You can render your provider like this

```js
<GlobalContext.Provider value={{
  array,
  removeFromArray: this.removeFromArray
}}>
  <Routes />
</GlobalContext.Provider>
```

Also it's not clear what it `this.removeFromGutka()` in the function that you have added to the state.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. About the `removeFromGutkas()` function, it was a mistake in copying from the codebase.